# How to replace fckeditor with CKeditor?

Tags: drupal-6, ckeditor, fckeditor

I have installed the fckeditor in my drupal site.
Now I want to replace it with CKeditor. Any Idea???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at it on the drupal site:

http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor

Suggests "How to install and configure the CKEditor Module" screen cast:

http://drupal.ckeditor.com/tricks#screencasts

Comment: I test the video but it is not playing in my browser. I test it on chrome, firefox and IE8

Comment: It's a youtube video, perhaps you don't have the required plugins or it's blocked by your network administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I indeed had problems doing so and I did not have one single site, more like 20 of them!

1. Permissions are not transported from the old to the new version, you'll have to edit your permissions (you may want to check them before uninstalling fckeditor so you can re-establish the same after ckeditor installation.)
2. Roles are not transported either. In the ckeditor settings, you'll have to edit each profile to re-establish which role has the right to use which profile. You want to do that after you setup the permissions. Also, as with the permissions, it may be a good idea to check out who was assign what before uninstalling fckeditor.
3. Toolbar are not properly transported (to not say not at all...) You'll have to reselect a toolbar (Basic, Advanced, etc.) and then tweak the bar to your liking before you can save a ckeditor's profile.
4. In case you were using the editor with filters that do not function well with entities, the old version had a patch that could be applied, the ckeditor version has a flag in the settings that can be selected to avoid having the editor transform characters in entities (an entity is a character such as &lt; which is mandatory, however, a character such as © is transformed to &copy; by the editor unless that flag is properly set.)

I wrote the steps with more details when I had to make the setup of my own websites:

http://linux.m2osw.com/updating-your-drupal-website-fckeditor-ckeditor

It was quite a bit of testing to get all of that to work properly!

Comment: Interesting comment considering that the two other answers are also just links.